# Как правильно использовать Swift протокол в Objective C?

Tags: swift, objective-c

У меня есть либа которая написана на Swift и я ее использую в проекте App как в Swift файлах так и в Objective-C (библиотека подключена правильно включая *-Swift.h файл)

В либе такая структура

Factory

```
import Foundation

@objc public class Factory : NSObject{
    @objc public func create() -> ModelProtocol
    {
        return FirstModel()
    }
}
```

Model protocol

```
import Foundation

@objc public protocol ModelProtocol
{
    func foo()
}
```

First Model

```
import Foundation

public class FirstModel : NSObject, ModelProtocol
{
    public func foo() {
        //Do some things here
    }
}
```

Когда я использую эту Factory в Swift то нет проблем он видит протокол и имплементации, в то время как в Objective-c он видит класс, но когда я пробую обратиться к протоколу получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'ModelProtocol'
```

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Lib-Swift.h"


@implementation ViewController : NSObject

- (void)foo {
    Factory *factory = [Factory new];
    ModelProtocol *protocol = [factory create];
}

@end
```

Так же загрузил проект и либу на драйв https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-DMYMhTqTqpgHcp31DNVby7US46OXUYM?usp=sharing

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Протокол в Objective-C не является типом, поэтому его нельзя использовать как переменную. Правильно будет так

```
id<ModelProtocol> protocol = [factory create];
```